# Types of Rules Don't Agree

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to write a program in SML for the following problem:

> A game is played with a card-list and a goal. The player has a list of held-cards, initially empty. The player
> makes a move by either drawing, which means removing the first card in the card-list from the card-list and
> adding it to the held-cards, or discarding, which means choosing one of the held-cards to remove. The game
> ends either when the player chooses to make no more moves or when the sum of the values of the held-cards
> is greater than the goal. Write a function officiate, which “runs a game.” It takes a card list (the card-list) a move list
> (what the player “does” at each point), and an int (the goal) and returns the score at the end of the
> game after processing (some or all of) the moves in the move list in order. Use a locally defined recursive
> helper function that takes several arguments that together represent the current state of the game. As
> described above:
>
> - The game starts with the held-cards being the empty list.
> - The game ends if there are no more moves. (The player chose to stop since the move list is empty.)
> - If the player discards some card c, play continues (i.e., make a recursive call) with the held-cards
>   not having c and the card-list unchanged. If c is not in the held-cards, raise the IllegalMove
>   exception.
> - If the player draws and the card-list is (already) empty, the game is over. Else if drawing causes
>   the sum of the held-cards to exceed the goal, the game is over (after drawing). Else play continues
>   with a larger held-cards and a smaller card-list.

And this is my solution:

```
datatype suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades
datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int 
type card = suit * rank

datatype move = Discard of card | Draw 

exception IllegalMove

fun remove_card (cs, c, e) =
    let
       fun delete_it (cs, c, e, count, acs) =
           case cs of
           [] => if count = 0 then raise e else acs
         | cp::cs' => if cp = c andalso count = 0
                      then delete_it (cs', c, e, count + 1, acs)
                      else
                          if cp = c then delete_it (cs', c, e, count + 1, [cp] @ acs) else delete_it (cs', c, e, count, [cp] @ acs)                
    in
       delete_it (cs, c, e, 0, [])
    end 

fun sum_cards (loc) =
    let
        fun sum_it (loc, sum) =
           case loc of
           [] => sum
         | c::loc' => sum_it (loc', sum + card_value (c))
    in
        sum_it (loc, 0)
    end 

fun score (loc, goal) =
    let
        val sum = sum_cards (loc)
        val all_same = all_same_color (loc)         
    in
        let
           fun prem_score (sum, goal) =
               if sum > goal
               then 3 * (sum - goal)
               else goal - sum     
        in
           let 
              val pre_score = prem_score (sum, goal)
              fun final_score (all, pre) =
                  if all
                  then pre div 2
                  else pre
        in
           final_score (all_same, pre_score)
        end         
    end
    end

fun officiate (loc, lom, goal) =
    let
    fun get_score (lcards, lohc, lmoves, goal, e) =
        case lmoves of
        [] => score (lcards, goal)
          | Draw::lmoves' => case lcards of
                   [] => score (lcards, goal)
                 | c::loc' => if sum_cards (c) > goal
                          then score (lcards, goal)
                          else get_score (loc', c::lohc, lmoves', goal, e)
          | d::lmoves' => case d of
                 Discard c => get_score (loc, remove_card (lohc, c, e), lmoves', goal, e)        
    in
    get_score (loc, [], lom, goal, IllegalMove)
    end
```

Ihe function `sum_cards` returns the values sum of the given card lists. `score` function returns the score of the game, while `remove_card` returns a list of cards minus the card provided. All these functions are working perfectly, but the problem is in the `officiate` function as I tried to use another two helper functions but without luck. This is the error log:

```
hw2.sml:196.17-196.60 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (suit * rank) list * (suit * rank) list list * 'Z * int * 
                   'Y
  operand:         (suit * rank) list list * (suit * rank) list list * 
                   move list * int * 'Y
  in expression:
    get_score (loc',c :: lohc,lmoves',goal,e)
hw2.sml:198.29-198.78 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (suit * rank) list list * (suit * rank) list * exn
  operand:         (suit * rank) list list * card * 'Z
  in expression:
    remove_card (lohc,c,e)
hw2.sml:192.27-198.78 Error: types of rules don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  earlier rule(s): (suit * rank) list list -> int
  this rule: move list -> 'Z
  in rule:
    :: (d,lmoves') =>
      (case d
        of Discard c => get_score (<exp>,<exp>,<exp>,<exp>,<exp>))
hw2.sml:192.27-198.78 Error: case object and rules don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  rule domain: (suit * rank) list list
  object: (suit * rank) list
  in expression:
    (case lcards
      of nil => score (lcards,goal)
       | :: (c,loc') =>
           if sum_cards <exp> > goal
           then score (<exp>,<exp>)
           else get_score (<exp>,<exp>,<exp>,<exp>,<exp>)
       | :: (d,lmoves') =>
           (case d
             of Discard <pat> => get_score <exp>))
val it = () : unit
```

I think this is because I used multiple case expressions.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `m` is of type `Move` so the expression `case m of []` is invalid.  what did you mean there?

Comment: Also the expression `if m = Draw then ... else case m of [] => ... | Discard => ...` seems unnecessarily complicated. Why not use a single `case`?

Comment: @qouify  Thank you, I didn't pay attention to the types. I have updated the function, and used one case for the Draw. As for `case m of []` I only included one match expression. What I don't understand is why SML assumes I'm passing a list in list `get_score (loc', c::lohc, lmoves', goal, e)` while I'm only appending the element `c` in the second parameter while passing the list `loc'` in the first parameter.

Comment: Well, what's the type of `remove_card`? You need to include a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `remove_card` type is a list of cards as you can see above in the code.

Comment: @ZakariaBennane SML is not assuming that, it follows from your code. `c` must be a list because it is passed to `sum_cards`, which has the type `card list -> int`, so `c::lohc` must be a list of lists. I think a useful exercise for you would be to write down all the types yourself.